# Infrared burn of eye

Tags: eye

Exposition 50 second.
4 infrared diodes(without visible light) 70 milliamper very close to eye.
Wavelength is 940nm. 
140 mW

Can it damage the eye?
May it cause infrared radiation burn?
If yes - what should I do?

Comment: very close, how much exactly ?

Comment: @ABcDexter  1 cm. Indirect